# Display message for 5 seconds

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I need to display the following message for like 5 seconds and then hide it.

The code to display the message is;

```
Ext.Msg.alert("Alert","How are you?");
```

and the code to hide the message is;

```
Ext.Msg.hide();
```

but how to display it for only `5 seconds` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var alertBox = Ext.Msg.alert("Alert","How are you?");
setTimeout(function(){
   alertBox.hide();
}, 
5000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using setTimeout should do the trick:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    Ext.Msg.hide();
}, 5000);
```